# Growing cells at specific indexes in Matlab using vectorization

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I wish to grow numeric arrays in cell arrays in matlab. Is this possible to vectorise? I need to this a lot of times so I am looking for speed.

In the code example below I use rand and randi to show what kind of data I am expecting. They are not part of the actual running code.

```
C = cell(8000, 9000);
for i = 1:8000
   idx = randi(9000, 1, 80); % Example of 80 index positions to grow at
   M = rand(10, 80);         % 80 arrays I wish to grow the cell array with

   % Here I wish to grow the arrays at C{i, idx} with columns from M

end
```

Thankful for your help

Comment: You can't vectorize this specific assignment: the cells contain separate mxArrays, so they need to be done as separate operations underneath the hood. But it probably doesn't matter too much in this case: `rand` and `randi` are themselves expensive, so your performance bottleneck is likely to be in the random number generation instead of the array expansion, which you're doing in good-sized chunks already. Try the simple for-loop version and throw it in the profiler to see if that's the case.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear but rand and randi was used to show what kind of data I was expecting, they are not part of the running code. I have  edited my question to clarify. So your answer is that it is not possible.. and no built-in stuff exists either?

Comment: Gotcha. So, yes - in the narrow sense, there's no built-in "vectorized" version of extension or assignment to multiple arrays, because vectorization usually happens across the elements of a single primitive array, or parallel arrays. To get it faster, you'd probably need to reorganize the loop so you're gathering all the input data (the rand/randi stuff) up front, and at the end, break it in to chunks to stick in the appropriate cells. Basically, try to minimize the number of "reallocations" that grow arrays. May have better advice if you can give more details on the input wrt shape & timing.

Comment: E.g. if you could slurp up all the input in a big `double` array, and then use `num2cell` or a smaller input loop to chunk it out in to the cells.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will give a more detailed description after the weekend to see if there are anything that can be done for the problem.